# quasiconformal groups construction

Tags: cv.complex-variables, group-actions, quasiconformal

I have seen the following statement recently:

Let $H$ be a Mobius group acting on $\mathbb{S}^n$ and $f$ be a $K$-quasiconformal self-homeomorphism of the $n$-sphere, then the group $fHf^{-1}$ is $K^2$- quasiconformal self-homeo of $\mathbb{S}^n$.

As I understand (intuitively) that is because both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are $K$-quasiconformal, and $H$ is 1-quasiconformal group, but I could not prove that given any $h \in H$ and $x \in \mathbb{S}^n$ then 
$$\lim_{r \to 0} \sup \frac{\max(\rho(fhf^{-1}x, fhf^{-1}y):\rho(x,y)=r)}{\min(\rho(fhf^{-1}x, fhf^{-1}y):\rho(x,y)=r)} \leq K^2.$$

Any hints are welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: how does qc coefficient behave under the composition of two maps?

Comment: @Misha as I think, quasiconformal function maps small circles to kind of small ellipses, so if the radius of circle is 1 unit then the smallest, resp biggest, distance becomes equal to some $a$, resp. $b$. $K = b/a$ for the function $f^{-1}$. Since $h$ is 1-quasiconformal it does not change. Now, under the action of $f$, the biggest distance of $fhf^{-1}$ comes from changing the previous biggest $b$ distance of $hf^{-1}$ to $b^2$. Similarly, the smallest distance of $fhf^{-1}$ is $a^2$. Therefore, $fhf^{-1}$ is $K^2$ quasiconformal, am I right?

Comment: A clean way to argue is to use the definition of K via derivatives. Then everything reduces to trivial linear algebra.